# Inner content pushes div down

Tags: html, css

I have a question about divs. I have multiple-divs in an parrent div, when I add content to the inner divs divs. The inner divs are pushed down?

I want to know why? Because all my mine margins and padding are add default 0;

Thank you for your time.

https://jsfiddle.net/3w50gj28/

```
<div class="boxes">
<div class="box">
    <h3>MyBMW Login</h3>
    <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Emailadres">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

---

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxes {
margin-top: 25px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
```

}

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 233px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 20px;;
}
```

Comment: Show some code,hard to tell without it

Comment: i added some code.

Answer (score 1):

div are Block-level Element and a block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available

Answer (score 0):

Margin and padding in this case aren't what is causing it. If you have divs stacked on each other, as you add content to one it will grow and push the div below down.